# Gatling report displaying incorrect group response time

Tags: gatling

Ran a load with 100 concurrent users for 1:30hr. The mean response times for the group 'Login Page' are higher than the mean response times of individual requests. How the group times are calculated exactly? I referred the docs for group timings[image] but i didnt get it.

Answer (score 1):

Means are bad metrics to use (mean of means is only statistically accurate, nothing to do with wanted accuracy in load testing).

For your concern, group duration is computed from the send of the first request to the response of the last request in the same scenario for the same user.

So, if your scenario contains pauses (or other time consuming computation), they are not included in individual request, but are in group.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but according to the Gatling documentation:

> 'Group cumulated response time is the time in a group when requests are
> flying: requests’ response time and resources start to end duration.
> In short, it’s the group duration minus the pauses.
>
> Group timings are by default the cumulated response times of all
> elements inside the group. Group duration can be displayed instead of
> group cumulated response time by editing the gatling.conf file.'

[gatling.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shJaX.png)